# How can I delete the old files from the location

Tags: batch-file

I want to delete the old files from different location except the latest file.

Suppose there are three folders at below location, I want to delete the files from these except the latest file.

```
F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD
```

below files in the folder, I want to delete all except 
`Expenses.05312013` (file names are variables)

```
Expenses.01312013
Expenses.02282013
Expenses.03312013
Expenses.04302013
Expenses.05312013
```

same goes for others too.

```
F:\Financial\Data\Reports\AccountPnlMTD
F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesMTD
```

New Edit:

F:\Financial\Data\Reports
F:\Financial\Data\Final Reports
F:\Financial\Data\Raw Reports

Each Above path has same folders (ExpensesYTD,AccountPnlMTD,ExpensesMTD..etc)in the end of the path.

I don't want to give path like this.

F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD
F:\Financial\Data\Reports\AccountPnlMTD
F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesMTD
and same process for the rest paths.

where is ExpensesYTD,AccountPnlMTD,ExpensesMTD folders are fixed so I want's to dirsribe only varibales paths in the script.

Comment: What tells you that `Expenses.05312013` is the latest one?

Comment: what is the **latest** ? Latest: create, write or read?

Comment: latest created in the folder

Comment: @Joey  yes "Expenses.05312013 " this time this is the latest on but next month it'll be older and latest file would be "Expenses.06302013"

Comment: to answer this we need your local date & time format (or country code).

Comment: 6/17/2013  2:08:00 PM (12 HRS)

Comment: Some advice: When embedding time stamps in file names (well, and in my opinion everywhere else) *always* use ISO 8601. It sorts predictably and saves you all sorts of headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution for `6/17/2013 2:08:00 PM` time format, look at the output and remove the word `echo`  before `del`  if OK:

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL
for %%i in (
    "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD"
    "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\AccountPnlMTD"
    "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesMTD"
    ) do (
    PUSHD "%%~i"
    for /f "tokens=4* skip=1" %%j in ('dir /a-d /O-D /TC /-C ^| findstr "^[0-9]"') do echo del "%%~k"
    POPD
)
```

Comment: Endoro..I tryed this but it's not deleting the files..However, It is showing  del "Expenses.01312013.csv" in the script.

Comment: If there is diffrent path like "F:\Financial\Data\Final Reports\ExpensesYTD" then how it'll work?

Comment: @nikiniki after the "alien" edit the main path is set in `%startfolder%` and the folders with files are set in `for %%i in (ExpensesYTD AccountPnlMTD ExpensesMTD) do`.

Comment: @nikiniki   if you change from `AM/PM`to 24h you must replace `"tokens=4*` with `"tokens=3*`. Not more, then it works.

Comment: How can I do this for morethen one path in one script like ""F:\Financial\Data\Final Reports\ExpensesYTD"  F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD

Comment: @nikiniki you can put all path names you want in the first for loop, look at my edit.

Comment: sorry to intrrupt you agin I have edit my question..to describe my needs. can we put all variables paths in script, b'z I have fixed folder name (around 25) in the end of each path...by this method I have to giv all 25 path for each path.

Comment: sorry, I gave more than four hours attention to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This has potential complications with Unicode file names, depending on the console settings. Consider yourself warned.

You can grab a list of files ordered by creation date with

```
dir /B /TC /O-D F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD
```

You can then iterate over that with `for` and delete each one, skipping the first (newest):

```
for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%F in (`dir /B /TC /O-D F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD`) do del "%%F"
```

Untested, but should work. As always when dealing with deleting files, have a backup ready in case things go wrong.

Comment: thx Joey..It would be great if you can you please provide the full codding including the path & all.

Comment: @Јοеу Unfortunately not for me :(

Comment: @echo off &setlocal
for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%F in (`dir /B /TC /O-D F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD`) do del "%%F"

Comment: @Joey..I hv created the batc as above...plz have a look if I missing somthing, However It's not working.

Comment: It needs to be run in the directory itself as %%F has no path information.